# How to get OnClick event of TextView in separate view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a small application which calls a web service using AsyncTask and based on the results returned populates a custom array adapter.

Since this is a separate view from the one that my activity is using, I keep getting the following error when I try to set an onClickListener I get the following error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lorentzos.swipecards.example/com.lorentzos.swipecards.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

This makes sense to me, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is my code.

My activity uses the following layout which does not have my TextView on it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

When the items are returned by the web service, I populate an arraydapter with the results and that arraydapter uses a different layout to display the results.

```
arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tradingcard, result);
```

My onClickListener looks like this and it is inside my activity onCreate() method:

```
TextView cardDesc = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardDesc);
        cardDesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //open up a fragment to display the entire carddescription
                //makeToast(getApplicationContext(), "Test description click");
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance for the help! I am really stuck how to access this TextView's click event from my activity.

One other question: I am trying to access the click event so that I can open up a popup or fragment to display more information, like a click through. This is a description field so it can have a lot of text but only a few lines will be displayed on the app, then when a user clicks on the description it should open up that field on another fragment to display the entire text and be scrollable. What is the best approach for this? Create a new fragment which opens up?

### EDIT:

activity_main.xml:

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:background="#d1d1d1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.5"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_noCardsLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#474747"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:text="No Cards Left to Swipe!"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <include layout="@layout/buttons" />
</merge>
```

tradingcard.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="415dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/outerMainCardLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/swipecard_shadow"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainCardLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="top">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_cardTitle"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#505353"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="Cement Pouring Guy"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_companyName"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#505353"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                tools:text="ABC Company"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_cardDesc"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#505353"
                android:background="#e6e7e8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:padding="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_swipe_left_indicator"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_swipe_right_indicator"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Card> card;
    private final int layoutResourceId;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Card> cards) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, cards);
        this.context = context;
        this.cards = cards;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService((Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardTitle);
            holder.companyname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_companyName);
            holder.description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardDesc);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        Card j = cards.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(j.getCardTitle());
        holder.companyname.setText(j.getCompanyName());
        holder.description.setText(j.getDescription());

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title;
        TextView companyname;
        TextView description;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i see your `activity_main.xml`, `tradingcard.xml` & `CustomAdapter` code ? please edit the question and attach it..!!

Comment: You could use an intent to pass data from one activity to another

Comment: @jankigadhiya added the code that you asked for! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2573690 `tv_cardDesc` is in Adapter you can not do `findViewById()` directly in Activity. Better to Access it in `CustomAdapter` or the requirement is you need to access the click in Activity only ?? You simply need to open the `Fragment` right? that you can do in Adapter also..!!

Comment: see my answer below @user2573690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove all `tv_cardDesc` related code from Activity including `onClickListener` & `findViewById`.**

Change your `getView` method of `CustomAdapter` like this :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService((Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardTitle);
        holder.companyname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_companyName);
        holder.description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardDesc);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    Card j = cards.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(j.getCardTitle());
    holder.companyname.setText(j.getCompanyName());
    holder.description.setText(j.getDescription());

    // JUST DEFINE THE CLICK LISTENER HERE

    holder.description.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //open up a fragment to display the entire carddescription
            //makeToast(getApplicationContext(), "Test description click");
            Toast.makeText(contex, "Test description click :"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**Explanation :**

> You have already done `findViewByID` for that `TextView` in
>   `CustomAdapter` so no need of doing it `Activity` just do it here &
>   **Main thing** : You can not access adapter's view in activity directly if want to so it you need an **interface implementation for
>   listView**. But for your problem the above solution is best.!!

Comment: Thanks! That works, so I was just defining the onClickListener in the the activity when it should have been in the adapter itself. That makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Edit your CustomAdapter like this

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<Card> card;
private final int layoutResourceId;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Card> cards) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, cards);
    this.context = context;
    this.cards = cards;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService((Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardTitle);
        holder.companyname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_companyName);
        holder.description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardDesc);

   holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //your code to do
        }
   });
   holder.companyname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //your code to do
        }
   });
   holder.description.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //your code to do
        }
   });

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    Card j = cards.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(j.getCardTitle());
    holder.companyname.setText(j.getCompanyName());
    holder.description.setText(j.getDescription());

    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView title;
    TextView companyname;
    TextView description;
}
}
```

Comment: What the difference between your answer and my answer ?? was i missing something that you added??

Comment: Nothing bro... when i was editing my answer that time you post your answer. After i post my answer i see we are same ........ i don't know what to do... if there is nay mistake .... forgive me please..